# I am having trouble in executing this sql query using php PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I run this function the `if` part gets executed, meaning that statement has some error.

```
public function retweet($tweet_id,$user_id,$get_id,$comment)
    {

        $stmt=$this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `tweets` (`status`,`tweetBy`,`tweetimage`,`retweetID`,`retweetBy`,`postedOn`,`likesCount`,`retweetMsg`) SELECT `status`,`tweetBy`,`tweetImage`,`tweetID`,:user_id,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`likesCount`,`retweetCount`,:retweetMsg FROM `tweets` WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id");
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_id",$user_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":retweetMsg",$comment,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id",$tweet_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo "failed to connect";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the PHP part?

Comment: I have added php part please check it

Comment: Well your edit says nothing about your problem? Include any erros and describe the problem more, please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please, please, tell us what's going wrong. *Having trouble* can mean anything from "my server caught fire and my data center burned to the ground" to "no rows were inserted in my table."

Comment: Now i have added my error deatils

Comment: https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php what does that throw you back? your `echo "failed to connect";` does not help you here. Get the real error.

Comment: `$stmt->execute();
        if (!$stmt->execute()) {` that is failing here, use the execute once, not twice.